# How to signup with Facebook without allowing "post as myself"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-integration

I’d love to sign up with Facebook wherever it’s offered, but if the app wants to "post as me", it’s a no-go. I don’t want some random app posting as myself.

Is there any way to get the best of both, namely signing up with Facebook but prohibiting "post as me"?

Answer (score 3):

You can often disable this permission after adding an app to your account.

1. Go to your Privacy Settings
2. Apps and Websites -> "Edit Settings"
3. Apps you use -> "Edit Settings"
4. Find the app you want to revoke the permission for, click the row for the app, then click the "x" to revoke any unwanted permissions on the app.